# How to build an image but not start it as a service using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

The case: I have the next project structure (kind of).

```
app
  -> Dockerfile
  -> folder
     -> Dockerfile
```

I use `app/folder/Dockerfile` as a parent image for a stage section in `app/Dockerfile`. My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    image: app
    build:
      context: .
      ...
    depends_on:
      - folder-image
  folder-image:
    image: ...
    build:
      context: folder
      ...
```

The problem and the question: When I run `docker-compose up`, `folder-image` gets built so I can use it to build `app`, but it is started as a service too. Is there any way to get only `folder-image` without starting it as a service? Or another approach to test?

Answer (score 1):

Run, `docker-compose build`. It will build the image but not run a service.